# System.Drawing.Image.FromFile not finding file that is there

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a program that populates an asp:repeater. The images show up with the following code

```
image.ImageUrl = "~/upload/max/" + product.Image1.ToString();
```

But when i try using

```
System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage =
    System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(image.ImageUrl);
```

i get a filepath error saying there is no file there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [Image.FromFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) takes a file name, not an URL.

If that code runs on your web server, you can use [HttpServerUtility.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to obtain the path to the physical file from its URL:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;

Image fullSizeImage = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(image.ImageUrl));
```